# How do I call a data inside a html tag in vue with es6 backticks?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js

I have a button in vuetify

```
 <v-btn text v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" router @click="$vuetify.goTo('{{link.routes}}',options)"> {{link.text}} ${link.route}</v-btn>
```

and script:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      links: [
        { text: "Home", route: "#home" },
        { text: "Download", route: "#download" },
        { text: "Register", route: "#register" },
        { text: "News", route: "#news" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

the `{{link.routes}}` wouldn't work. I guess I had to use backticks? but replacing it with `${link.routes}` didn't do the trick. What am I missing? Replacing `{{link.routes}}` with for example `"#downloads"` works, but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: No bracers needed. `@click="$vuetify.goTo(link.route,options)"`

Comment: OHH!! That was very stupid of me. Haha! THANKS ALOT!